# Beanshell code to call an API, parse JSON response

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to implement a logic where i do not want to send HTTP Requests unless an API returns 0 for a field. If i send the requests without monitoring response from this API, my test is invalid. API returns response in JSON, i can parse and extract the data i need to compare. Below is my test structure.

```
 Thread Group
  * While Controller
     * CSV Data Set Config
     * HTTP Request
     * JSON Path Extractor
     * Constant Throughput Timer
  * While Controller Condition: ${__BeanShell(source("function.bsh”))} != “0”
```

I want to call this API after every 5 minutes and proceed with sending HTTP Requests when field value is 0. I don't want to check before every HTTP Request just once before sending the first request. 
Can someone please help me with the beanshell code (function.bsh) to get API response and parse json response ? Was implemented using python as below

```
max_behind = 0
    response = requests.get("https://api")
    consumers = response.json().get("consumers")

    for total_behind in consumers.iteritems():
         max_behind += total_behind[1].get("total_behind")
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jmeter developers suggested "Better to avoid scripting languages in Jmeter". So in your case  use "If Controller" to resolve your blocker. Below are the details

1. Use regular expression to extract the "API return field" value, once you hold this value in a variable "valueIs". As shown in belo image

[image]

2. Use "If controller " and in condition enter the following value "${valueIs}==1", then add child requests ( next API call/calls) to "If controller". As shown below image

[image]